# Growing DIVs on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I wanna display a growing column when loading my website like this:

```js
function init() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('col')[0].style.height = '50px';
}
```

```css
.col {
  width: 20px;
  min-height: 1px;
  transition: height 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()" >
  <div class="col" ></div>
</body>
```

But as you can see it doesn't work. Would it theoretically help to have the onload-attribute placed in the attributes of the div? But that doesn't work, right?

I also could use keyframe animations, I guess. However, I actually have more column than one and all of them should grow to a different height. Therefore I would have to create a keyframe animation for each of my columns, which is kind of messy, I believe.

Does anyone know a clean solution to my problem? Thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work. It makes the column 50px high. What are you expecting? An animation? Your animation is contained in your CSS. Your height setting is contained in JS. The two don't interact like you are thinking. Make a second class `col-animate` set the height of that class to 50px and instead of using JS to set the height, use JS to add that class `col-animate`.

Comment: Are you able to use Jquery?

Comment: I am not, Danko. Should've said that.

Comment: And Leeish, actually that was my first attempt and it didn't work. However, I just realized this approach needs a height to be set in the first place, which is what I've added now. So everything works quite well, thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. Need webkit for Chrome/Safair I believe. Pretty sure you can't animate from min-height either as min-height is not a height. CSS transitions only work from set value to set value.

```js
function init() {
  var d = document.getElementsByClassName('col')[0];
  d.className = d.className + " col-animate";
}
```

```css
.col {
  width: 20px;
  height: 1px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  background-color: red;
}

.col-animate {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()" >
  <div class="col" ></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be good to write like below example CSS to support more possible browsers

```
.col {
 width: 20px;
 height: 1px;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s; // webkit - chrome safari
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;   // Opera
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s; // Mozilla
 background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I believe that Mozilla now supports transitions without -moz- but I could be wrong. Also, you have a typo in your css. It should read `-moz-tran...` and `-o-trans...` `kit` is part of `-webkit-`

Comment: @Leeish, thanks for the observation, some of the old version of Mozilla might requires "-moz-transition"